# How to loop multi dimensional array and insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an associative array that I'm receiving through JSON decode. I need to be able to input different parts of this array such as names into a user database. I've been researching and have found ways to do it with simple arrsays, just not this big of an array. The array is set up as follows:

```
array (
  'status' => 'success',
  'facility' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'id',
    'url' => 'url',
    'name' => 'name of divison',
    'atm' => 'cid',
    'datm' => 'cid',
    'ta' => 'cid',
    'ec' => '0',
    'wm' => 'cid',
    'fe' => 'cid',
    'roster' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'cid' => 'cid',
        'fname' => 'name',
        'lname' => 'name',
        'email' => 'name',
        'rating' => 'rating',
      ),
```

I've attempted using this code but it didn't return anything.

```
$rating = $json['facility']['roster']['rating'];
var_dump($rating);
```

Ive standardized the values due to privacy issues. There's about 38 other users in the roster array that need to be inputted to MySQL database. If anybody knows how I could so this it would be greatly appreciated if they could share.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a code writing service. We're not here to build your system for you. Doesn't matter where the code/data comes from, the mechanics of inserting into a database remain the same.

Comment: Show the code you have tried with, and where you have an issue.

Comment: Yes it's not inserting the data into a database I'm having trouble with. It's turning the specific elements in the database into variables so they can be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably

```
$json['facility']['roster'][0]['rating'];
```

If you are splaying the JSON into a database, you probably have (at least) two tables - `faculty` with about 9 columns and `roster` with about 6 columns.  And there is a 1:many relationship between them.  The 6th column would be `faculty_id` to facilitate the 1:many.

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Is it possible to iterate through all 38 users to input into the database?